# How to concatenate 2 seperate folders

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, directory

i am trying to concatenate 2 folders and those folders should copy to new folder using command line in Ubuntu.

i used `tee` command but its creating one more folder in second folder of input folder.

Comment: what do you mean by concatenating folders?

Comment: consider if folder A and folder B is there , now i want those folder to be concatenate in folder C i.e folder C should contain folder A and folder B.

Comment: should C contain the contents of A and B, or should C contain two folders, A and B, with their original contents?

Comment: C contain two folders, A and B, with their original contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
rsync -aP /ORIGINAL_A/* /DESTINATION_C/ORIGINAL_A/
```

This is like a copy of the folder A

```
rsync -aP /ORIGINAL_B/* /DESTINATION_C/ORIGINAL_B/
```

That should concatenate the folders A and B to another the new folder C.

Comment: this is copying content only, i need full folder to copy

Answer (score 0):

guys i got the answer,

```
cp -R source destination
```